# Select non-unique id where no row meets criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have this table, and I want to select the IDs where all D is < 4. In this case it would only select ID 1 because 2's D>4, and 3 has a D>4

```
+----+---+------+
| ID | D | U-ID |
+----+---+------+
| 1  | 1 | a    |
+----+---+------+
| 1  | 2 | b    |
+----+---+------+
| 2  | 5 | c    |
+----+---+------+
| 3  | 5 | d    |
+----+---+------+
| 3  | 2 | e    |
+----+---+------+
| 3  | 3 | f    |
+----+---+------+
```

I really don't even know where to start making a query for this, and my sql isn't good enough yet to know what to google, so I'm sorry if this has been asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply do:

```
select id
from table
group by id
having max(d) < 4;
```

If you happened to want all the original rows, I would use a window function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(d) over (partition by id) as maxd
      from t
     ) t
where maxd < 4;
```

Comment: Thank you - I had to change it a bit because I got an error about aggregate functions in a where clause, but this worked for me:
select id from table group by id having max(d) < 4

Comment: @sgeddes I know! It looks so simple this way I don't know how I didn't think of it!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select id
from yourtable
group by id 
having count(case when d >= 4 then 1 end) = 0
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11677e/1)

---

If you need all the data from the corresponding rows/columns, you can either `join` back to the table using the above, or alternatively you could use `not exists`:

```
select *
from yourtable t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from yourtable t2
    where t.id = t2.id and
          t2.d >= 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this query.

select ID from yourtablename where D < 4;

Comment: But then I get 1,1,3,3, when I only want 1

Comment: use sub-query and handle it. i.e., select distinct ID from yourtable where ID not in (select id from yourtable where D >= 4);